# Getting error "Font shape undefined" - explain solution?

Tags: fonts, koma-script, fontspec

When compiling my document I get the error.

```
Font shape `TS1/TeXGyreTermes(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)  using `TS1/cmr/m/n' instead.
```

It's not stopping my document from being compiled correctly but it's just really annoying getting this warning.
I already found out that I am able to fix it with the command: `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{TS1}{\rmdefault}{udidot}` by looking at the documentation of the obsolete package `substitutefont` over [here](https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/substitutefont/substitutefont-doc.html).

with this MWE you can reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}


\begin{document}

asdf

\end{document}
```

as you can see its coming from the combination of the tree packages `\usepackage{gensymb} \usepackage{textcomp}` and `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`
If I only use `gensymb` I get the warning:

```
Not defining \perthousand.
Not defining \micro.
```

which can be fixed witht he usage of package `textcomp` but this is producing the initial error.
can somebody explain to me, why this is happening and what the command `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{TS1}{\rmdefault}{udidot}` is actually doing?

Comment: don't use textcomp or gensymb packages for legacy tex encodings with fontspec for unicode fonts

Comment: you mean the packages are just not necessary anymore?

Comment: T1 encoding only has 256 characters so the TS1 encoding was added to allow an extra font so allowing another 256 characters but you are using TU (Unicode) encoded TeX Gyre fonts that can have several thousand characters in a font so no, they are not only not necessary they are, as you see, harmful and break the unicode setup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `textcomp` or `gensymb` packages for legacy tex encodings with fontspec for unicode fonts. –

T1 encoding only has 256 characters so the TS1 encoding was added to allow an extra font so allowing another 256 characters but you are using TU (Unicode) encoded TeX Gyre fonts that can have several thousand characters in a font so no, they are not only not necessary they are, as you see, harmful and break the unicode setup.

In recent latex releases `textcomp` isn't even useful in classic 8 bit latex or pdflatex as it is essentially preloaded and TS1 encoded fonts are available by default.